# How to exclude the relation column from the collection result array- eager loading

Tags: php, model, laravel-8, eager-loading

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude/hide the relationship column in the eager load collection result array

I have 2 models and here are the relations

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
    {
        public function Category()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
        }
    }
```

**Category.php**

```
class Category extends Model
    {
        public function Product()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
        }
    }
```

**Table fields**

> ***Category***: *id*, name
>
> ***Product***: id, name, *category_id*

so, here is my query

```
$result = Product::leftJoin('product_tags', 'product.id', 'product_tags.product_id')
        ->with(['category' => function ($q) {
            $q->selectRaw('id,name as category_name');
        }])
        ->select('product.id', 'product.name','product.category_id',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT(product_tags.product_tag)) as product_tag'))
        ->groupBy('product_tags.product_id')
        ->paginate($limit)
        ->toArray();
```

here is the response

```
{
    "id": 50,
    "name": "three",
    "category_id": 2, // this field I need to exclude from result array
    "product_tag": "123,3",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "category_name": "Azo"
    }
}
```

below is the response I'm excepting

```
{
    "id": 50,
    "name": "three",
    "product_tag": "123,3",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "category_name": "Azo"
    }
}
```

I've tried doing it like so:

1.

```
$result['data'] = collect($result['data'])->except(['category_id']);
```

2. $result['data'] = collect($result)->transform(function($i) {
   unset($i->category_id);
   return $i;
   });

even I tried to use the `except()` helper function but seems all the efforts are meaningless

NOTE: I'm aware I can set protected properties in the model (**$hidden or $visible**), I might want to use it in different contexts and want to use the default pagination of laravel.

Is it possible and any way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't want it, Just don't provide in the select method. `->select('product.id', 'product.name',DB::raw...`

Comment: @BadPiggie I tried that if I don't provide in the select method then it gives me a null category object -> `category:null`

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-eager-loading-specific-columns?page=1&replyId=29387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first try, every child will have `category_id`, not the primary array.

```
collect($result)->map(function($item) {
    return collect($item)->except('category_id');
})->toArray();
```

On the second one, you're using `toArray()` in your main array so to unset `category_id` you need to use the `[]`

```
unset($i['category_id']);
```

PS: I see `paginate()` it's the result of this the result of an endpoint? In that case, you can check out [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources).

Comment: Hey, the second one ```unset($i['category_id']);
``` resolve an issue - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `makeHidden()` method.

```
$paginator = Product::leftJoin('product_tags', 'product.id', 'product_tags.product_id')
        ->with(['category' => function ($q) {
            $q->selectRaw('id,name as category_name');
        }])
        ->select('product.id', 'product.name','product.category_id',DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT(product_tags.product_tag)) as product_tag'))
        ->groupBy('product_tags.product_id')
        ->paginate($limit);

$result = $paginator->makeHidden(['product.category_id'])->toArray();
```